# Enumerable select list with string ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, enums

I am creating a drop down list of months for a registration form and I have used an enumerable range (0-12) for the database.  The problem is, I'm trying to add month names to make the form more user friendly, but I don't know how.

Here's the variable:

```
var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString("0"), Text = x.ToString() });
```

Here's the dropdown list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("", months, "Month", new { @id = "monthDropdown", @class = "selectpicker" })
```

How do I bind a string to each of the numbers in the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an array to store months:

```
var monthArray = new string[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May" ..}
```

Then change your `Select` statement:

```
var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString("0"), Text = monthArray[x-1] });
```